# How to create POJO from JSON with nested JSONString

Tags: java, pojo

Currently I have code that is receiving a POST request with a body of

```
{
  "EventBody": {
    "message":"{\"sysData\":{\"time\":1520865496235,\"data\":{\"appUUID\":\"randomnumber\",\"userId\":\"1801\"}},\"appData\":{\"testMessage\":\"Stuff to see\",\"ackURL\":\"http:localhost/generic\"\"}}",
    "client": {
      "device": {
        "device-id": 12345
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That body if being converted to a pojo object of as such

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventBody {

    // If state message object as type string I do get the string, if 
    // I keep it GenericMessage object I am met with a null object.
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public GenericMessage message;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class GenericMessage {

        @JsonProperty("sysData")
        public SysData sysData;
        @JsonProperty("appData")
        public AppData appData;

        public class SysData {
            public String time;
            public Data data;

            public class Data {
                public String appUUID;
                public Integer userId;
            }
        }

        public class AppData {
            public String ackURL;
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("client")
    public Client client;

    public class Client {

        @JsonProperty("device")
        public Device device;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public class Device {
            @JsonProperty("device-id")
            public Integer deviceId;
        }
    }
}
```

I am running into a problem of how to parse the / delimited string formatted as a JSON object. I have had it work by moving the GenericMessage class into its own seperate class and used by a service class to parse it with this method.

```
public GenericMessage convertGenericMessage(String message) throws MessageException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        if(message != null) {
            GenericMessage foundMessage = objectMapper.readValue(message, GenericMessage.class);
            return foundMessage;
        } else {
            throw new MessageException("Message field empty in event Object");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessageException("Exception while converting message to GenericMessage object: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But this is a bit ugly and introducing extra steps that I am hoping are unnecessary. Is there a way of calling some kind of implicit constructor for GenericMessage so that is parses the JSONString object?

Comment: Why do you need to move GenericMessage class outside ?